# Is there a language neutral API generator for wrapping Text/XML/JSON data services?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, rest, sqlalchemy

**Im trying to build a robust, object oriented, language neutral API on-top of JSON http services, so that I can change the underlying representation and structures of the data without breaking client side code that runs a website.**

(1) Is there a hibernate/ibatis/SQLAlchemy style API generation tool for the REST world ?  In particular, Im interested in putting a nice, clean API over a SOLR server, which serves up json data.  Or maybe I might just want to create a server side tool that can query a large list of text files, and serve those files as objects accessible over HTTP...

**The catch here, however, is that I want to do this in a language neutral way (using the hibernate analogy, I'd like my hibernate generator to generate DAO classes both in PHP AND in Java, for example).**

(2) More generically --- Is there a generic way to create hibernate/ibatis style object apis that works in the modern, http driven, NoSQL world ; hiding the underlying complexities of data location, storage data structures, connection handling, politeness , etc ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider rolling your own with a library such as [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/).

In fact, your tool could then be cross-platform and cross-language, as there are StringTemplate implementations for multiple runtimes.

You could also target multiple libraries for a single runtime, for instance in java you could either generate pure servlets or perhaps let the user use a library such as Restlets or Spring Mvc 3 which support an annotated style.

EDIT: Clarifying a possible solution

1. Create a way to describe the JSON function calls, analogous to a WSDL for Soap (don't know if this already exists)
2. Create a parser if it doesn't already exist for this metadata.
3. For each target language and run-time, create StringTemplate templates and some glue logic to select the right templates on output.  Each template should basically shovel data from your parsed metadata into a generated class.
4. Consider building the tool into existing platform tooling infrastructures (maven plugin, ruby gem, etc...)

Alternative approach:
For each target run-time, create a data binding library that will present a remote JSON api.  Create a data-binding metadata description that will be used to describe how to munge data into existing target language objects.  In java, this can be done in XML for example or with the use of annotations.

Comment: I'm thinking a low-level generator shouldn't be necessary, unless I'm misinterpreting your solution .  Could you clarify your solution ?

Comment: yes, a text generator.  This is how IDE wizards do it, too.  What needs to be clarified?

Comment: Would you rather it generate java .class files instead?  I think it'd be complicated as the client API can be variable, for instance in my example of Restlets vs Servlets, you'd want to generate different implementations, with perhaps the same Value Objects.

Comment: At least in java, the other alternative for data-binding is reflection and binding metadata.  See the approaches of Castor vs XmlBeans.

Comment: Thanks again.. I think your hinting at a process, but im still not clear here : I see the relevant technologies.  But - what is your proposed solution ?

Comment: I added some more details on the approaches

Comment: I think the approach might be workable, but i think still, that its a little bit low-level , at this point.  Maybe the tool for the job simply does not yet exist.

Comment: yes, i think it goes against the nature of json as a light-weight untyped data format, consider http://json-schema.org/